# My basic (free) account on AWS S3 is going to expire either it move to other plan or stay on basic (free)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have S3 basic (free) account which i have been using for last one year. In coming month it is going to be expired , my question what is its expecting behavior after expired whether it stayed in basic and charge me what i use or forced me to move other plans like developer , business. If it moved to developer account then should i have to pay $49 dollars or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no such thing** as a "free" AWS account.

There is, however, something called the [Free Usage Tier](https://aws.amazon.com/free/), which provides limited quantities of certain services at no charge during the first 12 months of the account.

For example, the Free Usage Tier includes 750 hours per month of a `t2.micro` instance running Windows *and* another one running Linux. If you stay within that level of usage, there will be no charge. A control panel is available within the AWS management console to **view consumption** of the Free Usage Tier.

At the end of the initial 12 months, the Free Usage Tier no longer applies and the account will be charged for these services based upon actual usage.

This is completely separate to [AWS Support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/pricing/), which has pricing tiers that you mentioned:

- Basic (no extra charge)
- Developer (a monthly flat fee)
- Business
- Enterprise

You are under **no compulsion** to subscribe to AWS Support. You can continue on Basic Support at no extra charge. However, if you are using AWS for production workloads, it would be advisable to subscribe to AWS Support so that you can ask questions about the service.

**Bottom line:** There is no need to change anything. However, you will be charged the list price for any services you consume after your 12-month period.